# Controlling table column widths

Tags: css, html, html-table

This looked like a simple task, but it turned out to be hard anyway.

A table with one row and two columns. Table width shall be 100%.

Column 1:
May contain a long text. Shall be displayed on one line only and overflow text shall be clipped. The width of this column shall be the width of the whole table minus the width of column 2.

Column 2:
Width of the right column shall be so that the text fits exactly. The text shall be right aligned.

In other words: the text of column 2 defines the width of the two columns.

The text of column 1 and 2 are dynamic, so absolute widths does not work. The width of the whole table shall be the width of the browser window, and this must work on all modern browsers, including mobile ones.

I have tried to use table and I have tried to use div's only. Both approaches looks promising, but I haven't quite solved it yet.

Here is some sample code I have tried: (problem: the table becomes more than 100% wide when the browser is narrow).

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class ="td1">
        This is a table. This is a very long text. Does it get clipped?
        </td>
        <td class ="td2">
            SHOW THIS
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Some CSS to go with it:

```
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .td1 {
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .td2 {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: visible;
        text-align: right;
    }
```

Attempt with a `div`: (problem: column 2 is ditched below column 1)

```
<div class="div1">

    <div class="div2">
        This is a very long text in a div tag. Does it get clipped?
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        SHOW THIS
    </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS to go with it:

```
    .div1 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .div2 {
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .div3 {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        float: right;
    }
```

This looks like a hard problem to me. Can anyone find a good solution?

**Update:**

Here is the whole html file, so it is easier for anyone to try this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
    .div1 {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .div2 {
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .div3 {
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: nowrap;
        float: right;
    }

    table {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .td1 {
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .td2 {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: visible;
        text-align: right;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="div1">

    <div class="div2">
        This is a very long text. Does it get clipped?
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
        SHOW THIS
    </div>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class ="td1">
        This is a table. This is a very long text. Does it get clipped?
        </td>
        <td class ="td2">
            SHOW THIS
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the div layout:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eDLNn/1/)**

### Markup:

```
<div class="div3">
    SHOW THIS
</div>
<div class="div2">
    This is a very long text. Does it get clipped?
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.div2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.div3
{
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this an option?

```
<div style="position:relative;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;">This is a table. This is a very long text. Does it get clipped?
    <div style="position:absolute;right:0;top:0;background:white;padding-left:5px;">SHOW THIS</div>
</div>
```